# Compile error: Incompatible operand types java.lang.String and char

Tags: java, drjava

```
import java.io.*;
import hsa.Console;
import java.awt.*;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        c = new Console();

        String sentence;
        String encrypt = "";
        String vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";
        final String PUNCTAUTION = ".,;?!\"\\/\' -";
        StringBuffer removePunctation = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer thirdLetters = new StringBuffer();

        char tempChar;

        //Open The Output File

        PrintWriter output;
        output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));

        c.println("Please enter the sentence you would like to encrypt");
        sentence = c.readLine();


        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
            tempChar = sentence.charAt(i);

            if (PUNCTAUTION.indexOf(tempChar) == -1) {
                encrypt = encrypt + tempChar;
            }
        }
        if (encrypt == 'A') {
            sentence.replace('A', '!');
        } else if (encrypt == 'I') {
            sentence.replace('I', '#');
        } else if (encrypt == 'E') {
            sentence.replace('E', '@');
        } else if (encrypt == 'O') {
            sentence.replace('O', '$');
        } else if (encrypt == 'U') {
            sentence.replace('U', '%');
        }
        c.println(encrypt.toString().toUpperCase());

        output.println(encrypt.toString().toUpperCase());
    }
```

I'm trying to remove all punctuation and spaces, and change the vowels AEIOU to !@#$%, but I'm getting an error. I am also trying to output the vowels I replaced from the sentence at the bottom and reverse them.

Comment: A few general remarks while reformatting your code:  You don't need `StringBuffer`, your `Console` collides with `java.io.Console`, and `String` is immutable, so calling `sentence.replace()` will create a new `String`, not modify the existing one.

Comment: I did indeed, deleted the comment.

Comment: I tried what they told me But nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [test strings for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), use [`String.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). For example, `"A".equals(encrypt)` tests if the string `encrypt` is the capital letter A.

Notice that, as above, it is preferable to put the constant string first (instead of `encrypt.equals("A")`) to avoid the possibility of a null pointer exception.

If you want case-insensitive matching, there's also [`String.equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29).

---

And regarding your task at hand (e.g., remove/replace all occurrences of something), you might consider using regular expressions instead.

For example, to replace all capital letter A with ! you could use something like:

```
encrypt.replaceAll("A", "!")
```

Or, if you'll be using the same regular expression pattern over and over again or want the flexibility to make case-insensitive patterns, then:

```
Pattern a = Pattern.compile("A", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
...
a.matcher(encrypt).replaceAll("!");
```

Comment: I am trying to Look for any A's in my Sentence that is inputted by the user and replace it with ! what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler is trying to tell you, you can't use `==` to compare a string with a character. The `==` operator works differently for primitives (such as a `char`) and reference types (such as a `String`) so conditions like `if(encrypt == 'U')` are nonsensical.

Comment: Then what can i replace it with?

Comment: Not sure, because the code doesn't make much sense to me. The string `encrypt` presumably ends up longer than 1 character, given the body of the `for` loop. Why would it ever be exactly 1 character? What are you trying to check? Additionally, strings are immutable, so `sentence.replace(...)` does not mutate `sentence`. It returns a new string, which your code discards. Like I said, the code does not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

A string is an object, while a char is a privative data type.

What you're basically asking the computer to do is a lot like asking it to compare a number to a list of numbers. It can't, simply because those are two entirely separate things.

As stated below, you want to use something like

```
  if(encrypt.equals("a")){
```

to campare a String to a char.